# How do download a file with a WebBrowser control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm working with a `WebBrowser` Control in Visual Studio.

I need to download a file with a `WebBrowser` component because of its `cookies` and savings that are made when navigating through it.

So I can't download it with:

```
WebClient 
or 
WebRequest.Create(URL) that will generate a HttpWebRequest
```

So I can download the file manually with

```
URL = "http://myurlofdownlaodexample.com/downloadfile.xml"
WebBrowser1.Navigate(URL)
```

But it shows a Messagebox asking to save the file in a given place.

So is it possible to downloa da file with `WebBrowser` without this box, or better:
is it possible to get a `Stream` to download the file via `WebBrowser`?

PS1:
I already tried to pass the cookies from WebBrowser to HttpWebRequest but it didn't work:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create (myUri);

request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer ();

request.CookieContainer.SetCookies (myUri, webBrowser1.Document.Cookie);
```

PS2:
I also passed the user agent and it didnt work also.

So I think the httpwebrequest doesn't belongs to another session so the server can't manage to download the file.

Comment: It's an interesting question.  Though I suspect the answer will be "no", I'm not sure.  However, I take issue with your premise that you can't use any other means.  The web server has no direct knowledge of the cookies on the client machine, so there is nothing in the cookies that could affect the way the server generates the response, unless the client is providing that data as part of it's communication with the server.  Whatever it's doing, you should be able to duplicate the behavior via an `HttpClient`.

Comment: VB.NET ≠ VBA. Please remove the incorrect one.

Comment: Since you specifically said that it's the WinForms control in a VB.NET project, I removed the VBA tag.  If I was incorrect in assuming this has nothing to do with VBA, please explain why.

Comment: ok vba removed.. do you have any Idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What about the cookies? Why do you need cookies for this? Both `WebRequest` and `HttpClient` can handle cookies if/when needed.

Comment: I tried to pass the cookies from WebBrowser to http request but it didnt work. I think I need to pass user agent and others... I cant get the useragent on webbrowser.

Comment: Do you mean, without saying it, that you need to login (authenticate an user) before you can download a file, because of a page redirection? If so, both `HttpClient` and `WebRequest` can perform the authentication **and** carry around session cookies. You'ld need a WebBrowser controls of some kind only when the page uses ajax/generic javascript to present a delayed page (filled by the server after it has been rendered). `HttpClient` is easier to use here. Search SO for `HttpClient` authentication if this is your scenario.

Comment: no, this page in particular, it is not need to authenticate this page... you said "You'ld need a WebBrowser controls of some kind only when the page uses ajax/generic javascript to present a delayed page " this is my case...